# How to set markers on google map after some time when coordinates in database changes?

Tags: google-maps

I am beginner to web and making a webpage with google map and a marker in it. Admin can moniter the position of mobile that sends its coordinates (longitude, latitude) to server after some time interval, these coordinates are stored in database with a particular id.

The position of marker should change when coodinates changes, I am unable to understand how it will be done.

I have made php file to fetch the coordinates but cant understand how to proceed further.

This is the webpage that i have made so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map { width: 1000px;height: 500px;}
    </style>         
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>
      var latlng = {lat: 31.54972, lng: 74.34361};
      function initialize() 
      {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');

        var mapOptions = 
        {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          title: "Hello World!"
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
      } 
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the php file to fetch coordinates from database:

```php
<?php
 define('HOST','localhost');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','coordinates');
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $query = "SELECT longitude,latitude FROM data";
  $qry_result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());       
   // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {
     $longitude = $row['longitude'];
     $latitide = $row['latitude'];        
   }             
?>
```

Comment: That's only 1 marker, right?  1 mobile phone that sends data, and every time this INSERTs a record into the DB table.  So when checking, we only need the last value.  Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Hi, use my latest updated code, I just edited it.  Let me know if it works for you

Comment: it's same as before just a marker at a fixed position it isn,t moving

Comment: can you e-mail me please?  emmanueldelay@gmail.com

Comment: yeah sure check inbox

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll first show you the result with test data, so you see how the map hehaves.

I add jQuery, to do the Ajax call. Ajax lets the webbrowser surf to any page on your site, without leaving the page.  The user doesn't notice anything going on

---

10 points on a line through Lahore.  Cookies store the index (0 to 9).

testdata.php

```
<?php  
  // this test loops a trajectory through Lahore, in 10 steps.
  // every 10 steps it goes back to the start
  // it's just test data, to show the map is working
  // $start = 31.468885630398272,74.24052429199217 
  // $end   = 31.572736162286912,74.43412613868712
  $i = (isset($_COOKIE['i']) ? $_COOKIE['i'] + 1 : 0) % 10;
  setcookie('i', $i);
  echo json_encode(array(
    'lat'=>31.468885630398272 + (31.572736162286912 - 31.468885630398272) * $i / 10,
    'lng'=>74.24052429199217 + (74.43412613868712 - 74.24052429199217) * $i / 10
  )); 
  exit;
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map { width: 1000px;height: 500px;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script>
      var latlng = {lat: 31.54972, lng: 74.34361};
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          title: "Hello World!",
          map: map   // replaces marker.setMap(map);
        });

        // now let's set a time interval, let's say every 3 seconds we check the position
        setInterval(
          function() {
            // we make an AJAX call
            $.ajax({
              dataType: 'JSON',   // this means the result (the echo) of the server will be readable as a javascript object
              url: 'testdata.php',
              success: function(data) {
                // this is the return of the AJAX call.  We can use data as a javascript object

                // now we change the position of the marker
                marker.setPosition({lat: Number(data.lat), lng: Number(data.lng)});

              }
            })
          }
          , 3000    // 3 seconds
        );
      } 
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

So now your real php file.

call it (for example) ajax.php.  Change 'testdata.php' to 'ajax.php' on line 31 of index.php

I think it should be this, though I didn't test it with a database.  Check it yourself

I assume you have an AUTOINCREMENT id, but this could also be done with a timestamp, or so

ajax.php

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','coordinates');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT id, longitude, latitude FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$qry_result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());       
 // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
 if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {  // whenever you only need 1 record, use "if" instead of "while"
   $longitude = $row['longitude'];
   $latitude = $row['latitude']; 
   // echo the object
   echo json_encode(array(
     'lat'=>$latitude,
     'lng'=>$longitude
   )); 
 }
 exit;     
?>
```